# Странное поведение 127.0.0.1 (+Microsoft Loopback Adapter)

Tags: windows, сеть, настройки, localhost

Всем привет! Вопрос скорее теоретический, то есть не о том, "как сделать, чтобы работало?", а о том, "почему оно так работает?".Итак, есть два компутера - 1) десктоп под WinXP Pro SP2, есть встроенная сетевая карта 2) нетбук под WinXP Pro SP3, встроенные сетевая и вайфай.Задача - настроить работу локального сервера Apache c несколькими виртуальными хостами. В файл host добавляются записи типа 127.0.0.1 site1.com127.0.0.1 site2.comВ апаче добавляются соответствующие виртуальные хосты.

А теперь загадки! На компе 1 все работает как хочется, причем работает независимо от наличия сетевого подключения и от того, включена или выключена сама сетевая карта. "ping site1.com" всегда дает обращения к 127.0.0.1.

На компе 2 работает, если есть работающее сетевое подключение (сетевая или вайфай - неважно), ИЛИ если настроить Microsoft Loopback Adapter (c такими параметрами: адрес 192.168.0.1, маска 255.255.255.0, DNS 127.0.0.1). Если не указать DNS в настройках Microsoft Loopback Adapter, то опять же не работает. Если нет активного сетевого подключения и не включен Microsoft Loopback Adapter, то на "ping site1.com" выдает что-то вроде "При проверке связи не удалось обнаружить узел .... Проверьте имя узла и повторите попытку".

Вопрос, я думаю понятен - ПОЧЕМУ оно так работает? Почему на компе 1 все работает вообще без каких-либо дополнительных действий, а на 2 толкьо с работающими подключениями? И почему Microsoft Loopback Adapter работает при DNS 127.0.0.1, ведь реально никаких dns-сервисов на компе нет?

Помогите разобраться!

Comment: охваще.. сколько нужно рассказать.. может разобьёшь это всё на отдельные вопросы и дашь им номера? тогда будет всё попроще.

Comment: А на втором, если сделать просто ping 127.0.0.1, то работает?

Comment: ArcherGodson, суть вопроса - определить причины такого поведения системы, остальное - это уже детали... pyatak, на втором компе "ping 127.0.0.1" работает всегда, даже если отключить все сетевые подключения и лупбэк адаптер. А "ping site1.com" работает в том случае, если есть какое-нибудь активное сетевое подключение - сетевая (если воткнут кабель работающей сети), вайфай (если есть соединение), или лупбэк, в любых комбинациях.

Comment: Главная загадка в том, что первый комп без прочих условий спокойно видит (из записей hosts), что узел "site1.com" - это 127.0.0.1, а второму для этого почему-то нужно какое-нибудь (любое!) сетевое подключение, в том числе и лупбэк адаптер.

Comment: Проверьте что на 2 в hosts прописан ваш site1.com. Получается что если пинг 127.0.0.1 работает всегда значит loopback тоже работает, проблема в резолве.

Comment: pyatak, в hosts все прописано, иначе как бы комп вообще понял, что нужно обращаться к самому себе, а не лезть куда-то... "Получается что если пинг 127.0.0.1 работает всегда значит loopback тоже работает" - нет, дело не в лупбэке. Я же написал, что 127.0.0.1 пингуется в любом случае, даже когда все соединения отключены, включая и лупбэк.